# Adding a new line to a CSV file with Python 3. Problems when last line is missing the \n

Tags: python, csv

Some files come with the last row having a `\n` and I'm able to write a new line like this:

```
with open(FILENAME, 'a', newline='') as csvFile:
     writer = csv.writer(csvFile, lineterminator='\n')
     writer.writerow(row)
```

But when the base file does not come with the `\n` at the end of the last row, the row I'm adding ends up in the same row than the last present row.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ideas. The new row your adding, maybe add '\n' at the start of it, that way it will appear on a new line.

Another idea, remove  "newline=''", and "lineterminator='\n'", see what happens. using 'a' in open() should be appending to a new line anyway.

Comment: Removing `newline=''` certainly doesn't hurt. But `lineterminator='\n'`is needed so I don't end up with two new lines after a line is writen. For some reason it adds two lines instead of one if I don't put that.
I was thinking that maybe I could read the last character of the file first, and if it's not an `\n` or `\r` then I should write the `\n` first and then continue.
That would be a workaround.

Comment: Ok I tested it and I experienced you issue. What I did find though was if I removed all the \n from the text it worked fine. If the lines did have \n on the end it didn't and I had to dictate the "lineterminator='\n'". So maybe do as you said and if the last charaters aren't \n, add it